# Not able install ruby gem Nokogiri 1.8.5 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, macos-big-sur

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.5' --source
```

I am getting this error after upgrading macOS to Big Sur, give me the suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try to run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.5' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` like the error message tells? What happens if you do, is there another error? What does that error tell?

Comment: There is no other error, other gems are installing but the problem is with nokogiri and upgraded macOS Big Sur.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: Did you try to install the nokogiri gem with the `gem install` command before running bundler? And did that work without an error message?

Comment: rails s
Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.5
.
.
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

The above lines are the errors. I tried sudo gem install, sudo gem install nokogiri -v "1.10.1" tried same error getting.

Comment: Why `1.10.5`? In your question, it seems like you have defined `1.8.5` in your Gemfile.

Comment: sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.5'
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.12 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224719/discussion-between-harishbn-and-spickermann).

Comment: Thanks for the time, I have upgraded to mac Big Sur so automatically ruby version upgraded to 2.6 but my app is running on 2.5 so the nokogiri dependencies not installed properly that was the issue, with RVM and dependencies installation it is resolved.

Comment: Answering here because the question is locked: BigSur changed how ruby is shipped and the ruby header file tree, and the gem commands are missing an include (-I flag). To fix, we can add a symlink: `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby && ln -s ../universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need install `libxml2` before install nokogiri.

`brew install libxml2`

See throubleshoting guide at https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: brew install libxml2
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!

executed the command, it is not resolving am getting same error